# r - How to create a multiple line graph where each line is a specified value of a column

Tags: r, ggplot2, linechart, geom-bar

I'm working with a bike share dataset that I've named "all_rides_v02".

Relevant columns are **day_of_the_week**(self explanatory) and **member_casual**(rides are logged as either casual or member)

```
$ ride_id         <chr> "99103BB87CC6C1BB", "EAFCCCFB0A3FC5A1", "9EF4F46C57AD23…
$ rideable_type   <chr> "electric_bike", "electric_bike", "electric_bike", "ele…
$ member_casual   <chr> "member", "member", "member", "member", "member", "memb…
$ date            <date> 2021-08-10, 2021-08-10, 2021-08-21, 2021-08-21, 2021-0…
$ month           <chr> "08", "08", "08", "08", "08", "08", "08", "08", "08", "…
$ day             <chr> "10", "10", "21", "21", "19", "19", "19", "13", "17", "…
$ year            <chr> "21", "21", "21", "21", "21", "21", "21", "21", "21", "…
$ day_of_the_week <chr> "Tuesday", "Tuesday", "Saturday", "Saturday", "Thursday…
```

I'm trying to create a line graph with multiple(two)lines where one line represents "member rides" and the other line is "casual rides". The x-axis would be day_of_the_week and the y-axis would be the number of rides(which is not explicitly logged in the dataset).

Any advice?

`ggplot(data=all_rides_v02)+`
`geom_line(aes(x=day_of_the_week, y=value, color=as.factor(member_casual)))+`
`geom_line()+`
`geom_point()`

I could probably post a dozen ways I've done it incorrectly. The main issue I keep running into is that I don't know how to work around not having the "y value". I just want it to be the number of rides.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd need to aggregate your data first. If you're using the full tidyverse, you can go

```
all_rides_v02 %>%
group_by(day_of_the_week, member_casual) %>%
summarise(count = n()) %>%
mutate(day_of_the_week = factor(day_of_the_week, levels = c("Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday")) %>%
ggplot() +
geom_line(aes(x = day_of_the_week, y = count, colour = member_casual))
```

Comment: From here, do you know how to reorder the days of the week to be Monday-Sunday? Currently it is alphabetical. I tried plugging in a factor into the aes() but not having luck so far.       


geom_line(aes(x= factor(day_of_the_week, levels=c("Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Sunday")), y =count, color=member_casual, group=member_casual))

Currently getting a "no applicable method for 'group_by' applied to an object of class "factor" message

Comment: I'm surprised that didn't work. I've expanded my answer for another possible solution.

Comment: Ah, I found an error on my part for why it didn't work. I had forgot to change my dataframe title when tinkering. Working now, but so did your expanded answer.